# Adding a table to java swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, jpanel

I already have a panel to which I have added buttons and a text area. Now I need to display a table below it . The panel's layout is AbsoluteLayout and if I use the following method to inflate the table it shows up empty

```
        String data[][] = { { "vinod", "BCA", "A" }, { "Raju", "MCA", "b" },
                { "Ranjan", "MBA", "c" }, { "Rinku", "BCA", "d" } };

        String col[] = { "Name", "Course", "Grade" };
        JTable table = new JTable(data, col);
        table.setLocation(25,343);
        panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

However when I use setbounds the table display okay but  it takes up more space than it requires and the lines dont show in the empty space and it looks bad. Does anyone know how to set only the x,y location of a table and leave the rest of the positioning (width and height to accommodate just what is required)

```
String data[][] = { { "vinod", "BCA", "A" }, { "Raju", "MCA", "b" },
        { "Ranjan", "MBA", "c" }, { "Rinku", "BCA", "d" } };

String col[] = { "Name", "Course", "Grade" };
JTable table = new JTable(data, col);
table.setBounds(25,343,122,122);
panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: To have a clean layout, use a layout manager. AbsoluteLayout should not be used. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [do not use AbsoluteLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), caused issue on resize etc.
- put [JTable to the JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), don't to use [JPanel as container for JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)
- read Oracles tutorial about [How to use JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html),
- everything important is [asked, answered and described on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+jtable)

Comment: +1, when using a scrollpane you also need to add **table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());** so the table will fit completely in the scrollpane as the poster wants for this question.

Comment: Yep. table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());  definetely helped

Comment: @Developer Android right, but carrefully, this method is suitable for small JTables view with a few rows & columns, have to test for Dimension came from PreferredScrollableViewportSize, otherwise GUI can going to the MilkyWay :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add (Box.createVerticalStrut(343), BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add (Box.createHorizontalStrut(25), BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.add (new JTable (5, 5), BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```